# Mixing fully rendered and partially rendered pages with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, angular-ui-router

In my web app I keep part of the pages fully rendered on the server side (to make them easily indexed by google) and some of the pages should be rendered partially with AngularJS. Rendering full pages is straightforward, however, I'm confused when I want to mix it with partially rendered pages.

The problem I see is how to make it possible to navigate from a fully rendered page to partially rendered? Let's say that I have a fully rendered page at the following url: fakedomain.com/products/all Now, I want to allow users to edit their profiles and this would be a partially rendered page (available at fakedomain.com/#/user/profile). 
How should I do all the routing and rendering?

I mean, when user clicks the option to edit his/her profile should I render index.html where I have ui-view declared? If yes, how do I make sure that correct partial is used?

btw. I'm using NodeJS on the server side and I'm pretty new to the client side stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJS html5 mode https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location which takes away the hashbang. Then you need to route all requests to your app to the index.html (which loads angularjs).

You need to add exceptions for your static pages routes on your nodeJS app or your webserver, so that the requests for the static pages get handled correctly.

That should work allright and keep it an integrated experience for your users.

Comment: why 2 identical answers?...please delete one

Comment: Did it through the web app.